# Moq DbContext with async test throwing error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nunit, moq

I have got problem with this test:

```
    [Test]
    public async Task Add_async_vaild_test_entity_to_database_should_be_added()
    {
        // Setup Moq
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<SingleChoiseTest>>();
        var mockContext = new Mock<NoezaTestContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.SingleChoiseTests).Returns(mockSet.Object);

        // Perform action
        var operations = new SingleChoiseTestOperations(mockContext.Object);
        await operations.AddSingleChoiseTest(new SingleChoiseTest("question", new Answer("d1", false),
            new Answer("d2", false), new Answer("d3", false), new Answer("d4", true)));

        mockSet.Verify(t => t.Add(It.IsAny<SingleChoiseTest>()), Times.Once);
        mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChangesAsync(), Times.Once);
    }
```

I'm testing this function:

```
    public async Task AddSingleChoiseTest(SingleChoiseTest singleChoiseTest)
    {
        if (singleChoiseTest == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("Test cannot be null.");

        if (!singleChoiseTest.IsValid())
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Test is not vaild.");
        }

        using (_context)
        {
            _context.SingleChoiseTests.Add(singleChoiseTest);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

When I run the test it's throwing below exception: 
System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: m => m.SingleChoiseTests

Answer (score 0):

As the error is trying to tell you, you can only call `Setup()` for `virtual` members.

You need to make `SingleChoiseTests` virtual.